# What do tweezers do?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs, synonyms

The other day, I had an acne blemish that I couldn't reach. Naturally, my wife was all too happy to take care of it for me. It turned out there was an ingrown hair inside. She said "I can't get it out with my fingernails. Do you want me to tweeze it?"

I stopped breathing for a moment. "Did you just say 'tweeze'? Like, as a verb?" and she replies "What else would tweezers do?"

Dictionaries say that the verb "tweeze" is a back-formation from "tweezers." What is an alternative verb for what tweezers do? I'm looking for something that would have existed independently of tweezers themselves. Ideally, a reference would exist that doesn't involve 'tweezers', but would be a standalone verb.

Comment: You tweeze with tweezers. http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tweeze

Comment: I don't know if it counts to reference tweezers in the definition of tweeze. Seems like cheating.

Comment: @Stephie If you'd like to see a comment as an answer, you are welcome to convert it yourself. Though of course it's courteous to wait a bit to see if the original commenter would like the points himself, and if/when you do convert it, crediting the commentor is also polite.

Comment: @sumelic I'm looking for something that doesn't involve "tweezers" themselves. I couldn't find a word that stands alone.

Comment: I don't understand. It seems to me that "tweeze" does stand alone. Look at the example on this page: "tweeze facial hair." http://www.thefreedictionary.com/tweeze Do you mean you want a word that could be used to describe the action of other instruments? If so, it would help if  you added more examples.

Comment: @corsiKa: In the given M-W link, and also in [Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/tweeze), the word tweeze is listed as a *back formation* of tweezer.  This means that no, it is not a stand-alone word.

Comment: @sumelic every single citation there references tweezers. "To handle or extract with tweezers." "to take hold of or pluck (hair, small objects, etc) with or as if with tweezers". Clearly, not standing alone.

Comment: @DanBron, knee-jerk reaction (or good conditioning): http://meta.cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/2157/what-should-we-do-with-answers-in-comments-on-questions

Comment: At https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/tweezers, it says that "in the 17th century a tweeze was a case of surgical instruments".  Later on "tweeze" became "tweezer", which meant that "tweezes" became "tweezers".  Apparently the name of the case itself was at some point reassigned to one of the tools inside.

Comment: Approaching the question from a different angle...tweezers are a tool used for holding something securely enough that with backwards force, the held object can be plucked or removed from their original location - such as with an ingrown hair or a sliver.  They are like tiny pliers, which come to think of it, would not really be said to "ply", would they? :-)

Comment: You can ply (join by twisting) wires with pliers. Hamming with a hammer is another matter.

Comment: By the way, you should also show your research. Have you looked in a thesaurus for "tweeze"? For example: https://www.powerthesaurus.org/tweeze If so, what did you think of the synonyms?

Comment: http://etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=hammer  It doesn't look like the "er" of hammer is that morpheme.

Comment: Tweezing is for hairs, not acne pimples. You pluck or tweeze hairs. You should not let your wife use tweezers like that on you. Geesus. It's dangerous, it can worsen infection and scaring. Normally, pimples are popped. You put a kleenex over it and gently apply pressure with two fingers...

Comment: @KristinaLopez The thing is the tool (noun) *hammer* from Old German *hamor*, *hamur* or *homer* (original word thought to have meant "stone weapon"), and dating from Anglo-Saxon England (pre-1066) preceded the verb *to hammer*. The first OED reference for the latter is 15th century.

Comment: @KristinaLopez *Pliers* are almost certainly from the verb *to ply* meaning to "bend, bow, fold or double* (OED).

Answer (score 10):

As an American, I'd like to judge words, not on their heritage, but on the content of their... definition. "Tweeze" is a fine word.

If you truly need an alternative: **pluck**. Obviously, this is but one of the many things that tweezers can do, but fits nicely for your example.

> Do you want me to pluck it?

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pluck

Comment: In the context of removing an ingrown hair, *pluck* is the winner.

Comment: According to the tone of the question, this answer may no longer be correct after someone invents "pluckers".

Comment: Too bad, I was really hoping to be the answerer. :-P

Answer (score 4):

You [tweeze](http://merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tweeze) with tweezers. You should thank your wife for undertaking this mission for you.

Comment: The reference you cite specifically uses tweeze as a back-formation of tweezers. I'm looking for something that would have existed independently of tweezers themselves. (After all, if tweeze existed before tweezers, then how did the name tweezers come about?)

Comment: @corsiKa Asking how the name tweezers came about seems like a totally separate question. Do you have some kind of problem with back formations?

Comment: @DCShannon I think corsiKa is trying to find something like "squeeze" + "tease" (in the sense of *tease out*) = "tweeze", but I think WS2's answer nails it :) .

Answer (score 3):

**The verb *tweeze* is a back formation from *tweezers*, the OED's first recorded instance of which is from 1932.**

***Tweezers*** derives from the French ***etui*** being a case of small instruments, for manicuring and other purposes.

> Forms:  Also pl. tweeses, twizes, twises; rare in sing.
>
> **Etymology:  Aphetic < etweese (1657) = etuys , etuis , plural of etui
>   n.  See also twee n.1 The form-history in English is not quite clear,
>   but apparently the plural form etuis, etwees was taken also as
>   singular and spelt etweese, and this aphetized to tweese.**
>
> Thesaurus »
>        A case of small instruments, an etui; also pl. instruments kept or carried about in a small case. Occas. a pair (= set) of tweezes.>
>
> [1611   R. Cotgrave Dict. French & Eng. Tongues   Pennarol de
>   Chirurgien, a Chirurgians Case or Ettuy; the box wherein he carries
>   his Instruments.]
>
> 1622   J. Mabbe tr. M. Alemán Rogue (1623) ii. 130   Whether shee
>   would buy a very fine paire of twizes which we..had cut from another
>   gentlewomans girdle..having ground and whet them..and fitted them with
>   a case.
>
> a1627   T. Middleton & W. Rowley Spanish Gipsie (1653) ii. sig. C2v,
>   Take any thing.., Purses, Knives, Handkerchers, Rosaries, Tweezes, any
>   toy.
>
> 1632   R. Sherwood Dict. in R. Cotgrave Dict. French & Eng. Tongues
>   (new ed.) (at Tweese),   A Surgeons tweese (or box of instruments).
>
> 1638   J. Ford Fancies i. 7,   I will..betallow thy tweezes.
>
> 1645   J. Howell Epistolæ Ho-elianæ i. xvi. 32,   I have sent you..the
>   French Bever and Tweeses you writ for.
>
> 1665   R. Boyle Occas. Refl. iv. xv. sig. Ff8v,   Drawing a little
>   Penknife out of a pair of Twises I then chanc'd to have about me.
>
> 1672   Descr. Lake Geneva in E. Halley Miscellanea Curiosa (1708) III.
>   409   There are found..Knives, and Needles as thick as Bodkins of
>   tweeses.
>
> 1681   W. Robertson Phraseologia Generalis (1693) 206   A barber's
>   tweese, or case of instruments.

Answer (score 1):

You use tweezers to do the sort of manipulation you typically do with fingers or fingernails but cannot due to size restraints. So any verb appropriate to using one's fingers is generally appropriate for using tweezers. Pluck, pull, grab, pinch, dissect, poke. In your specific example, "pluck" would seem to be the most appropriate. In this context, "tweeze" would mean "to pluck with tweezers." It confers the most accurate and concise description so I consider it the preferred word choice.